# Intelij do you know what this icon is that appears when edit has focus?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I select the Intelij editor the following appears

[image: What is this]

Sometimes it is a list of browsers sometimes clicking inserts code or a field definition.

I have version Ultimate 2019.2

Have been unable to find any mention of it anywhere, can you help?

Comment: **Where** it appears? On your cursor? **When** it appears? When you click on incomplete statements?

Comment: Appears when mouse enters editor window near top right hand corner. Not related to mouse position. Currently when clicked in java file will add:


 @FindBy(css="")
 private WebElement webElement;

Comment: are you using any plugin?